# PHPBB Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' overall_header.html.php

Tags: php, syntax-error, phpbb, phpbb3

Hi my problem is that I am getting this error here on ym PHPBB3 website

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /public_html/cache/tpl_anami_overall_header.html.php on line 309`

It happened when I installed a mod onto `PHPBB3` and it suddenly became like this.

**Notes: (Things that didn't work for me)**

1. I have tried deleting the files off the cache
2. I have tried restoring backups of previous dates

Also would my forum data such as posts, forums and topics be deleted if I would reinstall a new version of PHPBB3 into my directory with the same sql database? If this is possible, I would just reinstall phpbb instead

Thanks

Comment: this had an answer..i think. with a curly brace(}) in line 309?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is very simple error you are talking about. This should be solved by yourself. Use [PHP Syntax Checker](http://phpcodechecker.com) or other tools for this.

Answer (score 0):

The cache file is generated from `styles/anami/templates/overall_header.html`.

Open the cache file and look at line 309, find the matching line in the file above and fix the syntax error on that line, then clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

in a text editor open `styles/anami/templates/overall_header.html` and check every `<-- IF xxx -->` and `<!-- BEGIN xxx -->` statement opens and closes correctly. You may find you  have one too many `<!-- ENDIF -->` or `<!-- END xxx -->`